# Div with double arrow on top and bottom

Tags: css, html

I'm not an expert with CSS and I'm gonna be struggled in order to achieve the following shape for my div:

[image]

And then I would like to insert text in the center.

How can I obtain this shape ?

Below here, some my attempts:

```
 <div class="triangle-down-white" style="height:400px;"> 
                    try
                </div>
```

and css

```
.triangle-down-white {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-left:50%;
    padding-top: 4%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(140,  140,  140, 0.33);

}
.triangle-down-white:before, 
.triangle-down-white:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
     height: 122px;
     width: 122px;

    margin-left:-1000px;

    border-left: 1000px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1000px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid rgba(140,  140,  140, 0.33);

}



.triangle-down-white:before
{ /* hide arrow tails background */
      border-top: 100px solid white;
}
```

**UPDATE**
I added the new style chevron but the text appear behind the div. I'm using bootstrap and the html code is the following:

```
<div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-sm-12" id="chevron">
                <p>asdasdasdasasdaasdsadasadsadsasd</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The rest of the code is completely the standard one for bootstrap.

**SOLVED**

I added z-index: -1 at the new element.

Comment: I would make a normal div, with a background gradient. see here for more http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/

Comment: use `border` in combo with `:before` & `:after`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from [this website](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) here is the chevron shape you desire:

```css
#chevron {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
}
#chevron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
}
#chevron:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
}
p{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="chevron"><p>Hello</p></div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tried to apply this div to my row in bootstrap but when I try to write something it appears behind. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try increasing the `z-index` value in the `p` CSS :) If that doesn't work please update your question with the rest of the bootstrap styling.